# Making a Section 508-compliant accessible structure for a printable form

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, section508

I have a form which can be reviewed and printed after submission. Because it has to look good when printed, I don't simply want to display the same form with disabled fields, but rather want to display a 'read only' version that is formatted to look *like* the form. There are any number of ways to do this, but I am looking to comply with [Section 508 of the Rehabilitation Act](https://www.section508.gov/).

I created a sample below with three different ways I can imagine, with some CSS they all appear the same visually, but I am not sure which of these comply with the standards expected by Section 508.

Can you assist with that?

```
<div class="formreview">
<dl>
  <dt>Username</dt>
  <dd>user123</dd>
</dl>
<dl>
  <dt>Email</dt>
  <dd>user@email.com</dd>
</dl>
</div>
```

```
<div class="formreview">
  <h4 id="username">Username</h4>
  <p aria-labelledby="username">user123</p>
  <h4 id="email">Email</h4>
  <p aria-labelledby="email">user@email.com</p>
</div>
```

```
<div class="formreview">
<p>
  <span id="username" class="ff">Username</span><span class="fv" aria-labelledby="username">user123</span></p>
<p>
  <span id="email" class="ff">Email</span><span class="fv" aria-labelledby="email">user@email.com</span> 
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Unless you have specific criteria (like legal requirements to comply with section 508 of the ADA), this question is an opinion-based matter. if you do have specific criteria that are must-haves, please edit the question to include them, rather than asking about what is simply "better" or "preferred".

Comment: I did tag the question section508, and yes I am looking to comply with that, but in general I don't see how asking for best practices is a bad thing. I think the question is perfectly valid and would be helpful to others but if it is too opinion based, please flag it for removal. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for responding; not allowing best practices questions is not a matter of being a 'bad thing', but rather about the scope of the site. What constitutes a 'best practice' is the opinion of whoever you ask at the time, for the most part. Some people think comments in code are best practices, some think no comments in code are best practices (for one example).

Comment: As for section 508, again, thank you for clarifying. You may be surprised how many people use tags without thinking, so unless it's specified in the question, we generally assume someone using such a tag is simply trying to use any and all related tags and they don't _actually_ need to comply with it, or don't understand that, for example, wai-aria and section 508 are distinct standards.

Answer (score 0):

A [description list `<dl>` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element) is the most semantic way to mark up name/value groups like form field names and values:

> Name-value groups may be terms and definitions, metadata topics and values, questions and answers, or any other groups of name-value data.

But note that you shouldn't have a separate list for each form field; they should all go within the same list:

```
<article>
  <h2>Your Form Responses</h2>
  <dl>
    <dt>Username</dt>
    <dd>user123</dd>
    <dt>Email</dt>
    <dd>user@example.com</dd>
  </dl>
</article>
```

If you need to wrap each name/value pair in a `<div>` for styling or other reasons, that's permitted too.

```
<article>
  <h2>Your Form Responses</h2>
  <dl>
    <div>
      <dt>Username</dt>
      <dd>user123</dd>
    </div>
    <div>
      <dt>Email</dt>
      <dd>user@example.com</dd>
    </div>
  </dl>
</article>
```

Comment: While a `<dl>` might be the best semantic element, it unfortunately has different support from different screen readers. For example, your code example has two `<dt>/<dd>` pairs. Some screen readers will say this is a list with two elements and others with say it has four elements. Navigating with the screen reader's `i` key will sometimes go to both the `<dt>` and `<dd>` and sometimes it will only go to one of them.  It sucks that all screen readers don't treat the `<dl>` the same.

Comment: @slugolicious hopefully screen readers catch up to the spec soon